# issue with the code completion in Scala IDE for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala, ide, code-completion

I'm using "Eclipse for Java Developers 7.2" and Scala IDE 2.1.0. The issue is "code completion"...

I have "Use Scala-compatible JDT" and "Enable JDT content assist" enabled under my Eclipse.
Are there any other options I shuold turn on?

Comment: What's the issue?  Does it not work?  What are you doing exactly?

Comment: Yep, doesn't work. Only templates are displaying...

Comment: this still seems to be an issue with neon and trying to autocomplete in java files with an eclipse that has the scala IDE installed :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got luck to solve this.

The reason behind why this happens is because eclipse stores a .metadata file in  , which acts as a cache to load auto-complete suggestions.

If you try Project->clean, and then try the auto-completion the required java class members can be found in auto complete suggestions.

So the SOLUTION IS:
go to your eclipse.ini, in case of mac located at: 
/Applications/eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse.ini

and add "-clean" in the ini file just before "-project".

This has a down impact of that now your eclipse might take a minute or two longer to start for the first time. But for me , it was acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

re-enable all the following unchecked java content assist mechanism in the scala-ide preferences:

Preference window:
/Java/Editor/Content/Assist/Advanced

preferences to check in the 'default' content assist panel:

- Java Proposals

also enable the Java Proposals in the content assist cycling panel thats in the lower part of the window